# request for member `result' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I tried to search about this problem but I couldn't solve it. I tried to use struct and union but I think I'm not using it right.

I would like to use the array `result` the member of the `randomNum()` in another function. What is the best way to do it?

here is some of my code:

```
 void randomNum()
 {
    int i;
    int result[10];
    int x[10];
    int y[10];
    for ( i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        x[i]=  100+rand()%100;
        y[i]=   80+rand()% 90;
        result[i] = ( -2*(x[i]) ) + ( 5*(y[i]) );
        printf("Fitness = %d \n" , result[i]);
    }
}
```

I wanna use `result[10]` in this function:

```
void thebest()
{
    printf("Fitness = %d \n" , randomNum.result[2]);
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `result[10]`, then you'd better declare your array `int result[11]`!!!!  C array indexes are [zero based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Comment: And if you want to use "result[]" outside of randomNum(), then you'd better declare it outside of "randomNum()".

Comment: The context of your array should be global then you can use it is multiple functions. You said you are seeing some issues after making it global what is it?

Comment: I tried to use it as a global value but I'm not able to use the same value of this variable in the other function. 
I need to use the values of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access local values from outside a function. Instead, try changing `randomNum` to `return result[2]` at the end and change teh `void` in the signature to be `int`.

Alternatively, you could make `result` be a variable inside the `thebest` function, then pass it to `randomNum` to be filled in, then you can use it from `thebest` as a regular array.

But returning the specific item you're interested in from the `randomNum` function is probably the easiest and cleanest solution.

Also, when you call `randomNum`, don't forget the parenthesis: `randomNum()` instead at the usage point.

Comment: The array can be made `global`?

Comment: yeah, but that would be kinda weird too especially if calling the function twice in one expression

Comment: I tried to use it as global but the thing is I cannot use the same value of the variable of the first function in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
void randomNum(int *result)
{
    // same code except don't declare result[10]
}

void thebest()
{
    int result[11];

    randomNum(result);
    printf("Fitness = %d \n" , result[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access or change a member of randomNum.result[] that doesn't exist. The index of array, array_name[index] is from 0 to index - 1. Therefore, in the for loop to you need to change the it for i < 11 to i < 10 as it is the for loop below.

```
for ( i=0; i<10; i++)
{

            x[i]=  100+rand()%100;
            y[i]=   80+rand()% 90;
            result[i] = ( -2*(x[i]) ) + ( 5*(y[i]) );
            printf("Fitness = %d \n" , result[i]);

}
```

When trying to access the array it needs to be:

```
void thebest()
{
   printf("Fitness = %d \n" , randomNum.result[9]);

}
```

Comment: This is my problem I cannot use it this way
        "randomNum.result[9]"
it gives the same massage!

Comment: I see what you are doing. You cant use a function with a dot operator to access variables that are local to that function. You would have to make a struct with that name have either you x and y arrays with in the struct or in main. Also you have to call the function in order to use it.

Comment: if you would like i could make another answer showing what I mean

Answer (score 0):

C functions don't have class-like members, so you can't access `randomNum.result[2]` the way you do. There are a few other ways though:

**Caller-supplied buffer:**

The calling function can supply a buffer to be filled in by `randomNum()`. This is probably the simplest solution:

```
void randomNum(int result[10])
{
  int i;
  /* int result[10]; // Converted into a function parameter. */

  ...
}

void thebest ()
{
  int r[10];

  randomNum (r);
  printf ("Fitness = %d \n", r[9]);
}
```

This way, the `thebest()` function allocates storage for the array, and passes a *pointer* to `randomNum()`. It is not possible to pass an array directly to a function, so the array parameter in the definition of `randomNum()` is silently adjusted to a pointer to `int`, and the function call `randomNum (r)` will pass a pointer to the first element of `r`.

---

**Returning a pointer to static storage:**

If you want to access the `result` variable inside `randomNum()`, you can return it from the function. Similarly to the example above, you cannot return an array directly from a function. You have to return a *pointer* to the array. However, a local variable ceases to exist when the function where it is defined returns. To get around this you can define the variable to have *`static`* storage. This means that the variable exists throughout the entire execution of the program. It *also* has the drawback that two calls to the function will operate on *the same* variable, thus overwriting the previous data.

```
/* Define randomNum to return pointer of int */

int *randomNum(void)
{
   int i;
   static int result[10]; /* Changed to static */

   ...

   return result;
}

void thebest()
{
  printf("Fitness = %d \n" , randomNum()[2]);
}
```

---

**Returning a pointer to allocated storage:**

To get around the drawback of using a local static buffer, you can use a dynamically allocated buffer. This returns a new buffer on every call. Note that the allocation may fail (returning `NULL`), and that the pointer must be `free()`'d afterwards.

```
int *randomNum(void)
{
   int i;
   int *result; /* Changed to a pointer */

   result = malloc (10 * sizeof *result);
     /* Allocate 10 elements of whatever result points to */

   if (result) {

     ...

   }

   return result;
}

void thebest()
{
  int *r = randomNum();

  if (r) {
    printf("Fitness = %d \n" , r[2]);
  }

  free (r);
}
```

---

**Returning an array inside a struct:**

Ok, I lied before: There *is* a way to pass and return an array to and from a function. You can wrap it inside a `struct`. This has the drawback that, on some implementations, passing of large structs can be much more complicated than passing a pointer.

```
struct result_t {
  int result[10];
};

struct result_t randomNum(void)
{
  int i;
  struct result_t r;

  ...

    r.result[i] = ( -2*(x[i]) ) + ( 5*(y[i]) );

  ...

  return r;
}   

void thebest()
{
  struct result_t res;
  res = randomNum();
  printf("Fitness = %d \n" , res.result[2]);
}
```

**or:** (if your compiler conforms to recent C standards)

```
void thebest()
{
  printf("Fitness = %d \n" , randomNum().result[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help

I figure it out:

I need to declare the result[] in the main and then pass it to both functions:

```
  main(){
 int result[10];


 randomNum(result);
 thebest(result);


 }
```

pass result[] to the function()

```
  void randomNum(int result[])
       {
        ...

        }


   void thebest(int result[])
     {

     ...  
      }
```